# Prestashop product images

Tags: prestashop

After domain migration all of my product images doesn't work. I've tried to regenerate them, but it doesn't help aswell. Clearing cache also failed.

What can I try?

https://sklep.posbox.pl/

Comment: Try to disable/enable friendly URL.

Comment: yes it works when I disable friendly URL, but how to make it work with friendly URL?

Answer (score 0):

Tried to delete/rename .htaccess and then regenerate it by disabling/enabling Friendly URLs again?

Comment: Yes, I think I've tried all solutions from google, I've posted more info on presta forum: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/628100-product-images-issue/ I had problems with formating code here

Answer (score 0):

SOLVER: it was server side issue. We've disabled cache there (I had no idea it was enabled on server) and it works just fine.